# Setup wifi access on iPhone when out of range

Tags: iphone, wifi

I want to setup a wifi connection on an iPhone 6S.

I have the SSID name and WPA password.  But the wifi access point is out of range.  It is not my phone.  I want to set up the wifi name and password so that when the access point is within range in the future, it autoconnects.

When I try to add the connection it complains that it cannot connect, so it is wrong, so it won't save it.

Is there a way?  So far the only way I found is to setup a local wifi hotspot with the same name and password and connect to that.  I am not sure it works.

Comment: you won't be able to add an encrypted (WPA) access point that is out of range because the first time connection is different than re-connect, and on a first time connect keys are negotiated and stored,  the password is never actually stored in the form you see it... it becomes and is stored as an encrypted key.

Comment: Thanks.  I was afraid of something like that.  I am still waiting for the result of my try.

Comment: OK, regarding my try, the wifi didn't work at all.  So I don't know if it would have connected.  But after Tyson's comment I'd say probably not.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can set up a temporary access point at your present location with the same SSID and password, then connect to that?  I do not know if the iPhone is going to save some other router-specific identifying information which would prevent connection at the other location, but if you have two routers available to you where you are it would be pretty easy to test.

Comment: As I said, that is exactly what I did but I don't know yet if it works.  I created a hotspot on my mac.